# Smallest non-isomorphic strongly regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

**Motivation**: I want to see how the 3-dimensional Weisfeiler-Lehman algorithm (see [Logical complexity of graphs](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1003/1003.4865v1.pdf), p. 14) distinguishes between two non-isomorphic [strongly regular graphs srg(v,k,λ,μ)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_graph) in a specific example.

> **Question**: What are the smallest non-isomorphic strongly regular graphs
>   with the same v,k,λ,μ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This page http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~es/srgraphs.html lists some strongly regular graphs on few vertices, and gives two (16,6,2,2) graphs (which I didn't check but I presume they're non-isomorphic).  I imagine they're the smallest possible but I haven't checked: http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~es/16.vertices

Comment: The two (16,6,2,2) graphs are the Shrikhande graph and the line graph of $K_{4,4}$. The Shrikhande graph may be obtained by forming a 5x5 grid of squares, adding a diagonal in the same direction to each square, and gluing opposite edges of the square grid to form a torus.

Comment: I forgot to add: they are obviously nonisomorphic because the neighborhood of a vertex in the Shrikhande graph is a 6-cycle, whereas the neighborhood in the line graph of $K_{4,4}$ is a pair of 3-cycles.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, David.  Do you know if they are indeed the smallest, as they seem to be?

Comment: Yes, e.g. in http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/1817/1817A.pdf Brouwer and van Lint write that this is the only nonisomorphic pair with fewer than 25 vertices.

Comment: Peter Cameron discussed these graphs in a blog post recently: http://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2010/08/26/the-shrikhande-graph/

Comment: The links appear to be broken. In the meantime, http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/srg/srgtab.html has some information.