# What graph parameters are determined by parameters for strongly regular graph

Tags: graph-theory

Say two graphs are not isomorphic but are both strongly regular with the same set of parameters.  Are there any parameters (other than the usual such as order, degrees, eigenvalues and multiplicities, etc.) that are determined, e.g., independence number, chromatic number, etc.?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 10):

It's a classic result that a graph parameter called *Lovasz theta-function* $\theta(\Gamma)$ of a strongly regular graph $\Gamma$ is determined by its parameters. And the significance of $\theta(\Gamma)$ is that it is ["sandwiched"](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v1i1a1) between the clique number and the chromatic number.

In more detail, the parameters of the s.r.g. $\Gamma$ determine a 3-dimensional commutative algebra of symmetric matrices (the adjacency matrix $A(\Gamma)$ of $\Gamma$, the adjacency matrix of its complement, and the identity matrix span this algebra). Anything that can be expressed in terms of this algebra, which is specified by the eigenvalues of $A(\Gamma)$, is a parameter you are asking about, and $\theta(\Gamma)$ is one of them. Another one is the number of spanning trees, as by Matrix Tree Theorem it is determined by the eigenvalues.

Comment: Can you suggest a standard reference for this fact? Thanks!

Comment: For s.r.g.'s? Say, http://designtheory.org/library/preprints/srg.pdf

Or E.Bannai, T.Ito "Algebraic combinatorics I. Association schemes.", ISBN 978-0805304909.

Answer (score 3):

The number of cycles of length 3,4,5 are determined.  If the girth is 4, the number of 6-cycles is determined too.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the girth of a strongly regular graph would be determined by its parameters in the following way.  If $\lambda > 0$, then the girth is 3.  If $\lambda=0$ and $\mu > 1$, then the girth is 4.  If $\lambda=0$ and $\mu=1$ then the girth is 5.  That last case is a little unusual...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, well, I checked Brouwer's website and combined that with the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39312/smallest-non-isomorphic-strongly-regular-graphs) to the accepted answer of a question on this site.  I checked the complement of the Shrikhande graph versus the complement of the line graph of $K_{4, 4}$ using Sage and found independence numbers of 3 and 4, and chromatic numbers of 6 and 4, respectively.  Both are strongly regular with parameters (16, 9, 4, 6).  So, that answers my question for some parameters.

They have the same girth though.

Comment: What about the girth of the Shrikhande graph vs $K_{4,4}$?

Comment: @aaron Also equal.  Sorry, I was in a hurry last night so I didn't have time to say everything I should have said.

Comment: @aaron The reason I used the complements of those graphs was because the chromatic numbers and independence numbers were equal for the graphs themselves, all of those being 4.  But, I did check the girth for all 4 and the pairs with same parameters had equal girth.

Comment: If the girth of a strongly regular graph is not three, it is four and the graph is bipartite.

Comment: @chris The Petersen graph is strongly regular with girth 5... Did you say quite what you meant there?

Comment: @Louis You're perfectly correct. The key point is that the girth of a strongly regular graph is determined by its spectrum/parameters, as you've pointed out below.

Answer (score 0):

The diameter, energy and number of closed walks could be determined by parameters.